# Creating a personalization rule based on user LastLogin date

Tags: xconnect, personalization, sitecore-personalize

I have a requirement to create a personalization rule to change the rendering display based on whether the user is First Time user or New User.

The first-time user will be decided if the users **last login or contact. InterAction** is null.

The New User user will be decided if the users **last login or contact. InterAction date is less than 30 days.**

I want the Last Logged in date from the **Sitecore contact. InterAction**. How do I do **GetContact** and what do I need to pass as parameter. How do I get the **contact. InterAction value.** using xconnect.

Comment: What are you using for authentication? I would have thought the last login details would be stored on the user record vs the Contact

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore provides a flag to identify new anonymous users on the tracker:
**Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew**

You can use this in a condition as below:

```
public class IsFirstTimeUserCondition<T> : WhenCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
{
    protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
    {
        if (Tracker.Current == null || !Tracker.Current.IsActive) return false;

        if (Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew) return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

To check a contacts previous interactions, you need to call XConnect directly. A condition as below should satisfy your requirements:

```
public class IsNewUserCondition<T> : WhenCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
{
    protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
    {
        if (Tracker.Current == null || !Tracker.Current.IsActive) return false;

        using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            var references = new List<Sitecore.XConnect.IEntityReference<Sitecore.XConnect.Contact>>()
                {
                    new IdentifiedContactReference(Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource, Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N"))
                };

            var contacts = client.Get<Sitecore.XConnect.Contact>(references, new ContactExecutionOptions(new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey)
            {
                Interactions = new Sitecore.XConnect.RelatedInteractionsExpandOptions(LocaleInfo.DefaultFacetKey)
                {
                    StartDateTime = DateTime.MinValue,
                    EndDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-30),
                    Limit = 1
                }
            }));
            if (!contacts.FirstOrDefault().Entity.Interactions.Any()) return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

These conditions have been tested and work on Sitecore 10.1 XP.

References:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-platform/set-contact-facets-in-session.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-platform/get-contact-with-interactions.html